# searching issues in text "xman" for title "X-man last stand"

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch my data in  "X-man last stand" when I am trying to search with "xman" it's not giving the result.

My anaylzer is below, my below analyzer using **ngram** for indexing document i am using same "full_text_search_analyzer" analyzer

```
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "filter": {
    "english_stop": {
      "type":       "stop",
      "stopwords":  "_english_"
    },
    "english_stemmer": {
      "type": "stemmer",
      "language": "english" 
    },
    "english_possessive_stemmer": {
      "type": "stemmer",
      "language": "possessive_english" 
    }
  },
  "analyzer": {
    "full_text_search_analyzer": {
      "filter":[
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding",
        "trim",
        "english_stop",
        "english_stemmer"
      ],
      "char_filter": ["html_strip"],
      "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
    }
  },
  "tokenizer": {
    "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
      "type": "edge_ngram",
      "min_gram": 2,
      "max_gram": 5,
      "token_chars": [
        "letter"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you get when testing your analyzer with `POST xxx/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "full_text_search_analyzer",
  "text": "X-man last stand"
}
` ?

Answer (score 0):

After analysis, it is index and stored as these for words:
1. x
2. man 
3. last
4. stand
So, searching for "xman" is not matching any of it.

**Try to search as  "x man".**